# Why I get blank page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am on rails 4.2 app, when I view it into browser I just get blank page, strangely all routes work, but they all results into blank page, here is what I get:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="https://d2m2v9ix6oa4mz.cloudfront.net/assets/application-5ea496b2544e770dd32eddc798ebe844.css" />
  <script src="https://d2m2v9ix6oa4mz.cloudfront.net/assets/application-2020c3d1d37b4e77942c8d4b54d4b790.js"></script>
  <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
<meta name="csrf-token" content="PMSfAv88XZbAbSebUIfNCWS+aeesawxSz40C19iy1ze1ddR/htclFSd4CP/xkpAVR4hHUh1hVs3QkkOsHTQTVg==" />
</head>
<body>
  <style>
  .span7
  {
    width:550px;
  }
  .myContainer
  {
    width: 1050px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto
  }
  .h2{
    margin-left:100px;
  }
  .btn.jumbo {
  font-size: 21px;
  line-height: normal;
  padding: 9px 14px 9px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  }
</style>



</body>
</html>
```

here is how I start my app:

```
# rails s -e production
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.0 application starting in production on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
DEPRECATION WARNING: The configuration option `config.serve_static_assets` has been renamed to `config.serve_static_files` to clarify its role (it merely enables serving everything in the `public` folder and is unrelated to the asset pipeline). The `serve_static_assets` alias will be removed in Rails 5.0. Please migrate your configuration files accordingly. (called from block in <top (required)> at /var/www/web.com/config/environments/production.rb:26)
[2015-03-21 16:36:31] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-03-21 16:36:31] INFO  ruby 2.2.1 (2015-02-26) [x86_64-linux]
[2015-03-21 16:36:31] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=24129 port=3000
```

How to know what's going on? what's the problem?!

Comment: My guess is you left `yield` out of the layout file.  What's your default layout file look like?

Comment: My app works fine locally with production mode, but when try at VPS, I get blank page, so, how to investigate this?

Comment: You are showing the result. What does the original view `.erb` file look like? Is it running in `development` mode? And if so, did you check `development.log` for any interesting output?

Comment: the original .erb is the action partial view within the app layout, this works normally in production mode locally, it runs in production mode at VPS, production.log is empty, I don't know what's going on..

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to compile your assets.

run:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

on the production server and give it a go.

You can do this locally and push to your VPS also.

Comment: I have no problem with assets, the page is empty, if its an assets problem, then I would see broken images and broken CSS, but this is not the case..

Comment: This was just a guess based on what little information you've given. What VPS are you using? Can you look at the console for the production web server to see what it is returning? Are you pushing your code up to production with git? With as little info as you've given you will probably not get many answer.

Answer (score 0):

So not sure if this is your problem, but I had the same issue, and it turned out to be that I had commented the last few html lines in the `_header.html.erb` file, but had not closed the comment `-->`, thus it was effectively commenting out all the code on my page, leaving a blank page. Silly mistake.